# Iterating through table header in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click on a table header, I want to iterate through the list collection of headers, except for the one that was chosen, and toggle the class of the inner 'i' element.  This is what's I've tried. Doesn't seem to be working.

```
$('#img' + obj).not('thead tr th span').find.('i').toggleClass('fa fa-caret-up fa fa-caret-down');


<div id="tableContainer" class="im-col--9">
                        <table id="tablemain" class="im-overflow--scroll-y im-table im-table--compressed im-table--hover im-no-margin" style="height:20px;">
                            <thead id="tableheader">
                                <tr>

                                <th><input id="sel_DeSel_All" type="checkbox" value=""  style="width: 20px;"  class="tdcenter"/></th>
                                <th onclick=" fnjSort('Id'); " style="width: 145px;">

                                  <span id="imgId"  class="header" ><i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-lg"></i> ID </span>

                                </th>

                                <th onclick=" fnjSort('LastName'); " style="width: 150px; height: 20px">

                                    <span id = "imgLastName"  class="header"><i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-lg"></i> Last Name </span>

                                </th>
                                <th onclick=" fnjSort('FirstName'); " style="width: 150px; height: 20px">

                                    <span id = "imgFirstName"  class="header"><i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-lg"></i> First Name </span>

                                </th>
                                <th onclick=" fnjSort('MissingBills'); " style="width: 150px; height: 20px">

                                    <span id="imgMissingBills"  class="header wrap"><i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-lg"></i> Incomplete Tasks</span>

                                </th>

                                <th onclick=" fnjSort('Hospital'); " style="width: 150px; height: 20px">

                                  <span id="imgHospital"  class="header"><i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-lg"></i> Site </span>

                                </th>
                                <th onclick=" fnjSort('DischargeDate'); " style="width: 70px; height: 20px">
                                    <span id="imgDischargeDate"  class="header"><i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-lg"></i> DOD </span>

                                </th>
                                <th onclick=" fnjSort('Discharge'); " style="width: 40px; height: 20px">
                                   <span id="imgDischarge"  class="header"><i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-lg"></i> D/C </span>

                                </th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
```

Comment: Post your html.

Comment: Add your markup too

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/find/  you have an extra . after the keyword find.

Comment: Don't toggle `fa` twice - just keep it out of the toggleClass

Comment: *"Doesn't seem to be working. "* can you be a little less vague?  Errors in console?  Does nothing? Does something, but not what you want?

Comment: I added the markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
$('#img' + obj).not('thead tr th span')
```

says: find the node with id "img+id" then exclude it if it's a `span` - but *all* your `#img+id` nodes *are* spans.

Remove the `.not(...)` bit (and fix the typo) :

```
$('#img' + obj).find('i').toggleClass('fa-caret-up fa-caret-down');
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
find.('i')
```

use:

```
find('i')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a sintax error on find(), with one more dot (.)

```
$('#img' + obj).not('thead tr th span').find('i').toggleClass('fa fa-caret-up fa fa-caret-down');
```